# Get list of variable names in a class at run time

Tags: delphi

I have declared some simple classes in a program, e.g

```
MyClass = class 
    Var1 : Integer
    Var2 : Integer
end;
```

What I would like to do is to get  a list of the variables in this class ("MyClass") at run time (perhaps something like "GetPropList" for components?)

I have in mind something like this (obviously, the function "GetVarNames" doesn't exist, but I hope this gives the idea), which will pull the names of variables listed in "MyClass" into strings in a TStringList:

```
var
    MyVariableNamesList: TStringList
    i : integer;

begin
    MyVariableNamesList := TStringList.create;        
    MyVariableNamesList := GetVarNames(MyClass)

end;
```

Can anyone advise? Apologies in advance if this is a stupid question!

Comment: IMHO, I recommend publishing those fields and then use RTTI to grab(and possibly set) values

Comment: You can use RTTI for that, if the variables are published. Mybe this helps: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1406436/get-list-of-objects-methods-properties-and-events

Answer (score 5):

Depending on your Delphi Version you could use the new RTTI (introduced with Delphi 2010).

You could do something like this:

```
function GetVarNames(const AClass : TObject) : TStringList;
var lType : TRttiType;
  lContext : TRttiContext;
  lProperty : TRttiProperty;
  lField : TRttiField;
begin
  Result := TStringList.create;
  LType := lContext.GetType(AClass.ClassType);
  if assigned(LType) then
  begin
    for LProperty in LType.GetProperties do
    begin
      Result.Add(lProperty.Name);
      //Get current value:
      Result.Add(lProperty.GetValue(AClass).ToString);
    end;
   for lField in LType.GetFields do
   begin
     Result.Add(lField.Name);
     //Get current value:
     Result.Add(lField.GetValue(AClass).ToString);
   end;
 end;
end;
```

Comment: There is no need to create TRttiContext, nor to free it.

Comment: you forgot "end;" and to define AClassType as TObject, then, for LField in LType.GetFields do... then, using LField.GetValue(AInstance) you can also get current value of the field

Comment: @Linas: actually, you do need to `Create()` and `Free()` the `TRttiContext`, even though it is a record and not a class.  Internally, `TRttiContext.Create()` allocates and fills the RTTI pool if it is not already, and `TRttiContext.Free()` releases it if needed.

Comment: @RemyLebeau I don't know where you get this but if you look at the source code you could see that all the methods in TRttiContext calls EnsurePoolToken at first (same as in Create). So basically it is guaranteed that every TRttiContext method call has RTTI pool filled.